# Printing only in the final page with QuickReport

Tags: delphi, quickreports

Here is another question of ancient programming languages, if anybody knows how to print a calculated value only in the last page with Delphi 7 and QuickReport?

I was googling about two hours and I can't find any information on how to use this kinda reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the `QuickReport` and then expand the `Bands` property in the `Object Inspector`. Set the `HasSummary` band to True. You can use a `TQRExpr` component on the summary band and utilize whatever it supports for functionality to calculate your value, or use a regular `TQRLabel` or `TQRDBText` component and display the value you calculate manually in it's `OnPrint` event - just set the 'Value' parameter to what you want to display on the report.

And as @A.Bouchez said, it's not ancient technology. [Delphi](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi) is still very much alive and going strong - see the info on the newly released XE version at the URL provided. If you think it's ancient, you should bring your own knowledge up to date. :-)

Comment: i formatted the document to display values from my datasource but it generates around 100 pages and i display in the foot the amount of the values of the current list of records, and i want to show that amount only in the past page, the other records are fine doesnt matter but there it is the real problem, but thanks for the advice and i apologize to all delphi lovers, apparently im not at the last trend of technology as i supossed? haha :P

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps adding a band at the end of the report?

And we're not dealing about archeology here. Delphi is still alive: Delphi XE was just out weeks ago.
So this is not "another question of ancient programin' language", but "another question of ancient program"...